# How do I add my mobile device to my StackDriver profile?

Tags: ios, mobile, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

When I attempt to add my mobile device on the Stackdriver profile page, there is simply a modal that says: "Mobile devices can be registered from the Incidents section of the Cloud Console mobile app."

I vaguely remember doing this previously (over a year ago for the project in question), and it was working fine. Today I merged a few accounts and I can no longer add the 'Cloud console mobile app' notification method on any alerting policies because: 'No Cloud Console mobile app notifications configured'.

The only documentation I can find tells me to open the Incidents section on the mobile app, but there's nothing on there about registering the device. I have the latest version of the mobile app (currently 1.8.4 on iOS). Is this functionality still available? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to add your iOS device, you can simply log in to the Cloud Console mobile application with your project owner account, go under 'Incidents', click the three-dot menu icon on the top right corner, and select 'Register device for incidents after verifying your phone in the [profile settings](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/settings/). If you still not able to register, the new version (1.10.1) contains a fix on registering device for incidents.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it must have been an issue for a while in the iOS app (3-dot menu was gone), but I was able to register my device again just now.

I'm now getting an error on the Incidents page, but it seems unrelated to registering a device, so I'll address that elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the push notification for incidents are only supported on Android devices. See https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6143581?hl=en and Item #8 under Track Incidents